# MySQL: How to make sure update is always executed before select?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a web app that lets N number of users to enter receipt data.

A set of scanned receipts is given to users, but no more than 2 users should work on the same receipt.

i.e. User A and User B can work on receipt-1, but User C can not work on it(Another receipt, say receipt-2, should be assigned to the User C).

The table structure I am using looks similar to the following.

[User-Receipt Table]

```
+------------+--------------+
|  user_id   |  receipt_id  |
+------------+--------------+
| 000000001  |  R0000000000 |
| 000000001  |  R0000000001 |
| 000000001  |  R0000000002 |
| 000000002  |  R0000000000 |
| 000000002  |  R0000000001 |
+------------+--------------+
```

[Receipt Table]

```
+-------------+--------+
| receipt_id  | status |
+-------------+--------+
| R0000000000 |    0   |
| R0000000001 |    1   |
| R0000000002 |    0   |
| R0000000003 |    2   |
+-------------+--------+
```

★status 0:not assigned 1:assigned to a user 2: assigned to 2 users

1. select receipts from the receipt table whose status is not equal to '2'
2. insert the receipts fetched from the step 1 along with a user to whom receipts are assigned.
3. update the receipt status(0->1 or 1->2)

This is how I plan to achieve the above requirement.

The problem with this approach is that there could be a chance that the select(step1) is executed right before the update(step3) is executed.
If this happens, the receipts with status 2 might be fetched and assigned to another user, which does not meet the requirement.

How can I make sure that this does not happen?

Comment: Tip: don't store 'r'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all purposes, use  [`transactions`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html) :

```
START TRANSACTION
   your SQL commands
COMMIT
```

Transactions either let all your statements executed or not executed at all and performs implicitly a lock on the updated row which is more efficient than the second approach

You can also do it using [LOCK TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html)